# Pandas Dataframe splitted into weeks

Tags: python, pandas

I have problems reshaping a dataframe into weeks, such that I'm able to look at one particular week easy, but also aggregated week-days together, i.e. Monday + Monday, Tuesday + Tuesday, etc.

I have looked in the documentation for an approach, but I have not been able to find a solution that works for me. My data has a resolution of 1 min and a duration of 4 months, and the series has missing data at some locations.

Currently I have come up with something like:

```
def week_reshaping(df):
    # Define constant for offsetting the loop
    offset = pd.DateOffset(days=7)

    # Number of weeks within the df
    weeks = (df.index[-1] - df.index[0]).days // 7

    d_datetime = df.index[0]
    df_week = pd.DataFrame()
    for week in range(1, weeks + 1):
        start = df.index.searchsorted(d_datetime)
        end = df.index.searchsorted(offset + d_datetime)

        # Assign this somehow
        df.ix[start:end]

        d_datetime += offset

    return df_week
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I'm not entirely sure what your objective is here, but you should definitely consider using [groupby](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/groupby.html) rather than for loops (which will be much faster).

You can groupby the week (from the DatetimeIndex):

```
In [1]: rng = pd.date_range('2013', freq='D', periods=10)

In [2]: df = pd.DataFrame(np.random.randn(10), rng)

In [3]: df.index.week
Out[3]: array([32, 32, 32, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33, 33], dtype=int32)

In [4]: df.groupby(df.index.week).sum()
Out[4]:
           0
32  3.600673
33  0.791545
```

Similarly, you can groupby day (of the week):

```
In [5]: df.groupby(df.index.dayofweek).sum()
Out[5]:
          0
0  1.268307
1  0.387322
2  1.416948
3 -0.380844
4  1.464068
5  0.030965
6  0.205453
```

*or more complicated arrays derived from these...*

I think you'll be able to `apply` a different function here (rather than sum) to achieve the desired result.

Comment: As suspected I thought there was another approach :) Well, my final objective is to create histogram of the data-pattern for a day, week and month.

Comment: I think the count groupby method might help there. ...or perhaps value_counts i.e. `pd.value_count(df.index.dayofweek)`.

Comment: Interesting, however I'm not looking for how many entries there are in a particular day or week, but more like the mean or sum for day, week or month.

Comment: @aagaard then sum or more complicated analysis e.g. via apply :)